# Using PowerShell variables in CAML Queries?

Tags: powershell, caml-query

I'm trying to reconfigure scripts I made to move list items from one list to another. At the time the list were not going to change so all the variables were hard coded.

Is it possible to use a PowerShell variable in a CAML query?

for example

```
$IDNum = 2

$query = '<query>
<where>
<eq>
<FieldRef Name="ID"
<Value Type="Number">$IDNum</value>
</eq>
</where>
</query>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quoted string expand variables and single quoted strings do not.
Use like this:

```
$query = "<query>
<where>
<eq>
<FieldRef Name="ID"
<Value Type="Number">$IDNum</value>
</eq>
</where>
</query>"
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx

Comment: I've always seen it as `$($IDNum)`, did not know the parentheses were not needed.  Learned something new today :)